# build function arguments in ruby and reuse them for other functions

Tags: python, ruby

I have several functions in Ruby which I need to call with the same named parameter argument.
ex.

```
config = { 'options' => {'key' => 'val' }, 'stuff' => '123' }

foo(arg1, arg2, **config)
bar(newarg1, newarg2, **config)
```

again I am using **config as in kwargs in python.

I don't know how to do the equivalent in Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** Ruby 2.0 introduces the splat operator and keyword arguments, so if you are using Ruby >= 2.0 you can just use `foo(arg, keyword: arg_default)` and `foo(1, **{:keyword => arg})`.  If you are using Ruby 1.x then what follows applies:

---

Ruby 1.x doesn't have a splat operator for keyword arguments (in fact, Ruby 1.x doesn't even **have** keyword arguments).  Instead, you would simply have `config` as your last argument and users of your function can pass in a hash out of which you pull keys:

```
foo(arg1, arg2, config)
bar(newarg1, newarg2, config)
```

In *Python* you'd define `foo` and `bar` in this manner:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, **config):
    # config now contains any keyword arguments passed to foo
```

And call it:

```
foo(1, 2, some="key", another="value")
# or if you have a hash from elsewhere
foo(1, 2, **{"some": "key", "another": "value"})
```

In *Ruby* a similar construct is achieved in this manner:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, config={})
    # config is *still* a positional argument even though it has a default value!
    # do stuff with your configuration hash
    # as if it were a dictionary of keyword args
    # for example:
    default_config = {:options {:key => 'value'}, :stuff => 123}
    config = default_config.merge(config)
end
```

And it is called in this manner:

```
foo(1, 2, :some => 'key', :another => 'value')
# which translates into
foo(1, 2, {:some => 'key', :another => 'value'})
# the {} are optional for the last argument
```

If we were to translate that Ruby code *directly* into Python it would look *something* like this:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, config=None):
    # This is not *quite* exact because we can still call `foo(1, 2, config={})`
    # but I think it is as close as you can get in Python
    if config is None:
        config = {}
    # Now we can do things with the config dictionary.
```

And you would call it:

```
# Note: no ** (splat) operator in front of our dictionary
foo(1, 2, {"some": "key", "another": "value"})
```